# Django Rest get request parameters

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

Django request handler let you get POST parameters using request.DATA

```
def post(self, request):
    request.DATA.
```

How could I get DELETE parameters?
I tried

```
def delete(self,request):
   request.body
   request.read()
```

Both request.body and request.read() just displays csrfmiddlewaretoken and _method parameters.
For both of the above example I am sending the parameters as application/json.
How could I get the delete request parameters?

Comment: does `request.DATA` contain anything for your `DELETE` request?

Answer (score -3):

I know this question is quite old, but for reference: I think you might want Request.QUERY_PARAMS. See the REST Framework docs for more info: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests.html

Comment: check before posting the link